# Why Go reflect NumField() is only available on the type?

Tags: go, struct, reflection

I have the following Go code ([play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/mOyRM-QDvT7)):

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    name string
    email string
}

func main() {   
    uS := User{}
    uSt := reflect.TypeOf(uS)   

    fmt.Println( uSt )
    fmt.Println( uSt.NumField() )
    // fmt.Println( uS.NumField() ) // this doesn't work, why?

}
```

I'm just curious here. Why we need to get the type of the struct first before calling `NumField()`?

Why can't we just call it on the struct itself i.e. `uS.NumField()`?

From [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value):

```
type Value struct {
        // contains filtered or unexported fields
}

func (v Value) NumField() int
```

I'm not quite getting what is `Value` really means here. I do really appreciate concise explanation and examples.

Comment: You cannot call `uS.NumField` because `User` structure does not have a corresponding method.

Comment: You can't use `uS.NumField()` Because there is no `NumField` method defined on your custom `User` type--the same reason you can't call `uS.Foo()` or `uS.AnyOtherRandomMethod()`.

Comment: @zerkms @Flimzy then how `NumField()` actually works here? Does struct type is equal to `Value`?

Comment: And you can call `NumField()` after reflecting it because on `uSt` value your value is `Type` https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type returned by `reflect.TypeOf`

Comment: Reflection is really an advanced tool. If you don't feel comfortable with structs and methods - master them first. You would not need reflection unless you're doing something very wrong or very advanced: in the first case you'd need to change the approach, in the second - you would know how to deal with it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

> TypeOf returns the `reflection Type` that represents the dynamic type of
>   i. If i is a nil interface value, TypeOf returns nil.

From above statement it is clear that `TypeOf` returns `reflection Type`

```
func TypeOf(i interface{}) Type // return reflection type
```

Reflection type is defined in Golang as

> Type is the representation of a Go type. Type values are comparable,
>   such as with the == operator, so they can be used as map keys.

Value is the reflection interface to a Go value which you are using for Numfield method as receiver. As @Flimzy described that for any other reflection method also you need to use reflection value.

In your code:

```
uS := User{}
uSt := reflect.TypeOf(uS)
```

First value `us` is assigned with User type struct. While second value `uSt` is assigned as `reflection Type` from the returned value of `reflect.TypeOf`. Check the type of each variable:

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {}

func main() {   
    uS := User{}
    uSt := reflect.TypeOf(uS)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", uS) // Print the type of uS
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", uSt)
}
```

**Ouput**

```
main.User
*reflect.rtype
```

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/Ch7h7-04mS0)

For more information on how reflection works. Go through [Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)

Answer (score 0):

NumField() is a function of reflected structs and can be applied on any struct once you have reflected it.

It is NOT a function of User. You did not create any functions for User,
so I did to try to clarify

https://play.golang.org/p/c8oGa_56YfE